# take values from outside loop received inside loop

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How to receive a data/value that is created inside a loop outside the loop?
I really had searched on many sites,blogs and here, but I don't find the answer.

like this:

```
public  ArrayList<Dicionario> retornaArray() {
    controlaBanco = new controlaBanco(this);//the classe with methods to manipule the data in a database
    List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor = controlaBanco.carregaDados(); //this will give me the cursor with some data from a database(sqlite)
    arr = new ArrayList<Dicionario>(); //an arraylist formated to hand my data and then put it in a personalized listview

    int count = 0; //an number to control the data flow(it's 3000 linea of data and I guess my application might get slow by this

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast() && count <= 1000) {

//here I take the data from  columns separately
        str.add(cursor.getString(0));
        str.add(cursor.getString(1));
        str.add(cursor.getString(2));
        str.add(cursor.getString(3));

//here I take that data to formating this in my class
        dicionario = new Dicionario(str.get(0), str.get(1), str.get(2), str.get(3));

//here I put my formated data into my formated array
        arr.add(dicionario);

        count++; //the count is upping...
    }
//now I receive the array and returning this to my personalized adapter
    return arr;
}
```

but it doesn't work because it will just take and return the first line :(

Comment: ps: ahhh...the guys in other questions tell to initialize the values out of loop,but if I do it the values from the loop will be gone

Comment: when is `cursor.isAfterLast()` ?? (`== true`) ;)

Comment: I don't know hahaha .I see this in a turorial.a guy told to use this :) but if u r saying its wrong,I will change this to just "count<=1000" :)

Comment: no...you should do (something like) `cursor.next();` (within the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that **str** is having 4 elements added for each iteration. Yet you take values from elements 0-4 for (i.e. the first row).

There are various fixes, you could use :-

```
dicionario = new Dicionario(str.get(0 + (count * 4)), str.get(1 + (count * 4)), str.get(2 + (count * 4)), str.get(3 + (count * 4)));
```

- **str** would, at the end, contain 4 * number of rows elements

If you didn't want to use str after you could use `str.clear();` before assigning the values to str  e.g. :-

```
//here I take the data from  columns separately
        str.clear();
        str.add(cursor.getString(0));
        str.add(cursor.getString(1));
        str.add(cursor.getString(2));
        str.add(cursor.getString(3));
```

- in which case there would only ever be 4 elements in **str**

Or you could do away with **str** and directly apply the values from the current row by using :-

```
public  ArrayList<Dicionario> retornaArray() {
    controlaBanco = new controlaBanco(this);//the classe with methods to manipule the data in a database
    //List<String> str = new ArrayList<>(); //<<< not needed
    cursor = controlaBanco.carregaDados(); //this will give me the cursor with some data from a database(sqlite)
    arr = new ArrayList<Dicionario>(); //an arraylist formated to hand my data and then put it in a personalized listview

    int count = 0; //an number to control the data flow(it's 3000 linea of data and I guess my application might get slow by this

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast() && count <= 1000) {


//here I take that data to formating this in my class
        dicionario = new Dicionario(
            cursor.getString(0), 
            cursor.getString(1), 
            cursor.getString(2), 
            cursor.getString(3)
        );

//here I put my formated data into my formated array
        arr.add(dicionario);

        count++; //the count is upping...
    }
//now I receive the array and returning this to my personalized adapter
    return arr;
}
```

Personally I would use :-

```
public  ArrayList<Dicionario> retornaArray() {
    controlaBanco = new controlaBanco(this);//the classe with methods to manipule the data in a database
    cursor = controlaBanco.carregaDados(); //this will give me the cursor with some data from a database(sqlite)
    arr = new ArrayList<Dicionario>(); //an arraylist formated to hand my data and then put it in a personalized listview

    while (cursor.moveToNext() && cursor.getPosition() < 1000) {

       //here I take that data to formating this in my class
       arr.add(new Dicionario(
            cursor.getString(0), 
            cursor.getString(1), 
            cursor.getString(2), 
            cursor.getString(3)
        ));

    }
//now I receive the array and returning this to my personalized adapter
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but I think your code is wrong , your adding values to the Array str in the loop, but the array itself is outside and will return the same values for the first 4 (str.get(0), str.get(1), str.get(2), str.get(3)) unless you clear the array on every iteration.

Instead I would use dicionario =

new Dicionario(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

arr.add(dicionario);

Comment: yeah it's wrong but,in your code how can I take all the values?in your code u take just the first line,the others will be descarted like mine code :(